# Liquid Clustering - Retrigger clustering based on new keys

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

Adopting liquid clustering for our use cases, especially because partitioning is inflexible and zordering had problems like "optimize with zorder" taking too much time and conflicting with other jobs writing to the same table.

Liquid clustering mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/clustering).

It is mentioned that we can change clustering keys anytime , and the optimize that is triggered next, would only cluster data based on the new keys , going forward.

[image]

How can I trigger clustering of the whole table (historical data included), after change of clustering keys?

EDIT 1: I have read a bit more- though it is not mentioned directly anywhere, but reading about deletion vectors, shows that a rewrite can be done, using `REORG table`.
Now since liquid clustering enables deletion vectors, I believe, the same command could be used to recluster the entire table, using the new altered clustering keys. I wilk give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

As given in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/clustering#--how-to-trigger-clustering) you need to do regular `optimize` so that you can cluster the data.

Below the number of files on table which liquid cluster is enabled.

[image]

After running `optimize`.

[image]

Here you can observe 3 files have been removed and added 1 file.

Now I alter table for clustering data on `trip_distance` and `dropoff_zip`.
Then i insert some records.

```
alter table trips_cluster cluster by (trip_distance,dropoff_zip);
optimize trips_cluster;

INSERT INTO trips_cluster VALUES
("2017-02-16T22:40:45.000+0000","2017-02-16T22:59:25.000+0000",5.35,18.5,10003,11238),
("2017-02-16T22:40:45.000+0000","2017-02-16T22:59:25.000+0000",5,17,86513,07354)
```

[image]

and

[image]

If you see here 3 files are there. That is the new data is not clustered.
So for clustering the data you need to do `optimize`.

[image]

Now you can see that 2 files removed and added 1 files. That is, the data is clustered.

So, the table which are having frequent inserts or updates you need to do regular `optimize` to cluster with old data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don’t think you read my question properly. I know that optimize needs to be run and that is also mentioned in my question. What I am asking is here: how to trigger clustering of the whole table (including historical data), since MS docs mentions that only new data is clustered, not the old ones. You provided an example, but it only contains a few records, so running an optimize would always create one active file, because optimize aims at getting at 128 mb files. Please look at the scteenshot  i provided with the blue circle .